# How can I hide inline editing controls for a given security group?

Tags: permissions, rich-text, editing-menu

Does anybody know of a way of hiding the 'Edit' and 'Delete' controls provided within inline editing to people within the Viewers group?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

People in Viewers group can never have edit permission. Viewers can  only view the document not change or downlaod the document